# Not submitting default value in GET form

Tags: html, forms, get

I have a GET form to select a search filter.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="filter">
        <option value="">no filter</option>
        <option value="1">filter1</option>
        <option value="2">filter2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

If the user selects `filter1`, the url will be `/search?filter=1`, but if he chooses `no filter`, the url will be `/search?filter=`

I want it to be `/search`

How can I tell the form to only submit non-default values?

Comment: That is not possible using HTML only. You either need to interfere with JavaScript on the client (submit handler that checks what option was selected), or redirect server-side from `/search?filter=` to `/search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript or jquery to do this. 
Set an id to select list and perform javascript onchange event. if user will select no filter then name attribute will be remove so the filter type will not be the part of search but if user will select filter1 or filter 2 then name of select list will be filter so it will be showing in search variables.

```
     <form action="" method="get">
        <select id="filter" name="filter">
            <option value="">no filter</option>
            <option value="1">filter1</option>
            <option value="2">filter2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    <script>
$("#filter").change(function(){
if($(this).val()==''){
$(this).removeAttr("name"); // if no filter selected
}else{
$(this).attr("name","filter"); // if filter 1 or filter 2 selected
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write your submit function! So you can do as the following code:
1) change the type of input from *submit* to *button* and add the onclick property to point to your submit function;
2) there, you check for the value of select item, and if it is not selected, not to send any default value. 
3) using an empty form and change its method to POST.

Follow an example code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function mySubmit() {
    var url="/search";
    if (document.myForm.filter.value>0) {
       url=url+"?filter="+document.myForm.filter.value;
    }
    document.mySubmitForm.action=url;
    document.mySubmitForm.submit();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="mySubmitForm" action="" method="post"> </form> 
<form name="myForm" >
    <select name="filter">
        <option value="">no filter</option>
        <option value="1">filter1</option>
        <option value="2">filter2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:mySubmit();"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<option value="0">no filter</option>
```

and put validations on it

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you can't. You're submitting that data and no value is still a value.

Just use correct validation to check if filter is empty.